# Stretching iframe in HTML5

Tags: html, iframe, doctype

I have two html files, one contains the other with an iframe, and I want to make this iframe stretch over the full height of the parent html.

So the first html file (which has a red background) look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color: red; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <iframe src="Blue.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  height="100%" width="100%" />
</body>
</html>
```

The second (which has a blue background):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<body style="background-color: blue;" />
</html>
```

If all things are correct I expect to see only a blue background, because the iframe should overlap the entire parent page, but I see only a strip of blue, and a whole lot of red..

With the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` I cannot seem to be getting the correct result:

[image: With HTML5 DOCTYPE]

If I remove the HTML5 doctype I get the result I want. I think this is because it will render the HTML in quirks mode:

[image: Without HTML5 DOCTYPE]

I do want the HTML doctype though, so how can I fix this? Thanks for looking!

Comment: I'm doing that with my [W3 Viewer](http://w3viewer.com). The trick is to put the IFRAME in a DIV. Then position the DIV absolutely so that it covers the whole page, and set `width:100%; height:100%;` on the IFRAME.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CSS:

```
#wrap { position:fixed; left:0; width:100%; top:0; height:100%; }
#iframe { display: block; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <iframe src="..." frameborder="0" id="iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5G5rE/show/

Comment: Could you please explain why this issue happens and how the position:fixed fixes the problem? Thank you!

Comment: @Jay OP had set the height of the IFRAME to 100%. This percentage is in regard to the containing block - in this case the BODY element. However, the height of the BODY element, by default, depends on the height of its content. This is a circular dependency - the height of BODY depends on the height of the IFRAME, and vice versa. This won't work, obviously. One could set the height of both the BODY and HTML elements to 100% - that would work. I prefer fixed positioning - it's more flexible (one can define both the position and dimensions precisely).

Comment: The w3c school website suggests that the allowable units for height and width is restricted to pixels (not percent).  What gives?  http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Also, it seems you still must use fixed position (on the html/body) if you don't use a wrapper div otherwise you'll get a double vertical scroll bar.

Comment: @Ryan Notice that there is a difference between HTML attributes and CSS properties. The value of the `width` HTML attribute is indeed restricted to an integer value (representing a value in pixels), however, the `width` CSS property may contain a value in percentages, pixels, ems, and a bunch of other units. *** The IFRAME must be placed within an element that has `position: fixed`. I prefer to use a DIV for that purpose, which I place directly within the BODY.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas hi, thanks for such detailed comments, why it doesn't work when we use block without position:fixed, but with min-height:100% or any height in pixels (of course html+body and other wrappers have height:100%). But after i add height:100%, instead min-height:100% or min-height:500px, it starts working. Do you have any thoughts why it could happen? Do they check that parent block height was set in PX?

We need such things when we can't use position fixed (some cases when iframe shouldn't take 100% of the page etc. )

Comment: @Rantiev Could you make a demo of the issue you’re having?

Comment: #iframe { border: 0; display: block; width:100%; height:100%; } instead of frameborder="0" for HTML5