# Stretching iframe in HTML5 in display:Fixed

Tags: html, css

I was trying to stretch an iframe to all page and I maded with the next post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7011716

But below of the frame, I would like to add some buttons, something like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <iframe src="..." frameborder="0" id="iframe"></iframe>

    <p style="height: 25px;">
        <button ... />
        <button ... />
    <p>
</div>
```

But all the time the iframe covers all the web page and I have no way to show the small

until bottom or below of the iframe using 25px.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
#wrap { position:fixed; left:0; width:100%; top:0; height:100%; }
```

to this:

```
#wrap { position:fixed; left:0; width:100%; top:0; bottom : 35px; }
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/4BJ7f/

Answer (score 0):

Then try to make `iframe` height not 100%. Make it smaller ;)
Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zrFMc/) - it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Add buttons block inside #wrap and style absolute position.

html:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com/" id="iframe"></iframe>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button>Button</button>
        <button>Button</button>
    <div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#wrap { position:fixed; left:0; width:100%; top:0; height:100%; }
#iframe { display: block; width:100%; height:100%; border:0}
#buttons {position: absolute; bottom: 0;height: 25px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SQ6Fq/