# How to dynamically change width of iframe to fit properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

Working with Orderahead to allow online ordering for my clients simple one page website and I've been trying to figure out how to dynamically change the width of the iframe so that it can be properly viewed on smaller screens like iPhones. I've tried the numerous ideas out there but possibly I'm doing it wrong and hope someone here can help with a solution. The website and it's HTML can be viewed here: www.vngrill.com

Here is the JS I need to include in my head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//asset-hosting.s3.amazonaws.com/2-156/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//pixel-track.s3.amazonaws.com/2-156/pixel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//scripts.seo-optimizer.net/1/seo.min.js"></script>
```

Which in turns, loads the following into the page.

```
<iframe id="vn_grill_oo" width="100%" height="50px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" seamless="seamless" src="http://badges.orderaheadapp.com/html/widget.html?widgetStyleHeight=50px&amp;widgetStyleType=oa-full&amp;widgetStylePosition=oa-top&amp;widgetClassStyles=oa-dark%20oa-top%20oa-full&amp;businessName=VN%20Grill&amp;businessid=1413" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; z-index: 9999; top: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Iframe's height and width can-not be set in percentage's.... [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try using @media in css . . . e.g

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   //re declare your iframe classes here 

}
```

[details](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) click here

Answer (score 0):

This is a fluid solution, rather than using media queries. I believe that media queries should be used sparingly.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <iframe class="site" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}
.site{
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dustindowell/YfQ75/

Comment: **[Reference must be added if copied from some other answer...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7011716/2260614)**

Comment: @Bhavik I've never seen that post before.